# Are there any smaller, redistributable java compilers?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

My code requires a compilation of java source, and while I am using JavaCompiler API now, when run on a computer without JDK, it returns null.  I realize I can package the JDK with my program, but at over 100mb, it would be very large to include with a small program.  I have looked around for a third-party compiler, preferably smaller than the JDK, and would appreciate it if someone knew of one that can be added to my program.  (I'd plan on using a Runtime script to compile a set of files with it through command line.)

Comment: Without the class libraries, compilation wouldn't really work. How would the compiler check the signature of a method you're calling?

Comment: ...It sounds to me like you should just require that the user install the JDK themselves.  If your app requires compiling Java programs, then that's totally reasonable.  You don't need to distribute the JDK with your app; just require that users download it themselves.

Comment: @biziclop: If the target platform has a JRE, then it already has the class libraries needed to compile Java. Java compilers compile directly against class files; it's not like there are header files or anything like that.

Comment: @TomAnderson OP mentioned running the program on a computer without a JDK, I (mistakenly) assumed that to mean no JRE either. Of course if there's a JRE, packaging  `tools.jar` or Javassist can do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this project](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home). I didn't use it myself, but it looks like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to compile whole Java source files, or could you just compile individual methods? If the latter, Javassist can do what you need with [CtMethod.make](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtMethod.html#make%28java.lang.String,%20javassist.CtClass%29). It's [pretty straightforward](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#add).

Javassist isn't tiny - it's about 650 kB - but it's smaller than a JDK.